# Does a broken masterwork item retain its masterwork quality if enough Mending cantrips were cast on it?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, cantrips

I'm trying to repair a masterwork longsword a friend has in game; it had the broken condition.

Does a broken masterwork item retain its masterwork quality if enough Mending cantrips were cast on it?

Answer (score 2):

The entry on [broken](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Broken) weapons on the Pathfinder SRD says the following

> Items that have taken damage in excess of half their total hit points
>   gain the broken condition, meaning they are less effective at their
>   designated task. The broken condition has the following effects,
>   depending upon the item.
>
> - If the item is a weapon, any attacks made with the item suffer a –2
>     penalty on attack and damage rolls. Such weapons only score a
>     critical hit on a natural 20 and only deal ×2 damage on a confirmed
>     critical hit.
> - If the item is a suit of armor or a shield, the bonus it grants to AC
>     is halved, rounding down. Broken armor doubles its armor check
>     penalty on skills. If the item is a tool needed for a skill, any
>     skill check made with the item takes a –2 penalty.
> - If the item is a wand or staff, it uses up twice as many charges when
>     used.
> - If the item does not fit into any of these categories, the broken
>     condition has no effect on its use. Items with the broken condition,
>     regardless of type, are worth 75% of their normal value. If the item
>     is magical, it can only be repaired with a *mending* or *make whole*
>     spell cast by a character with a caster level equal to or higher than
>     the item’s. Items lose the broken condition if the spell restores the
>     object to half its original hit points or higher. Non-magical items
>     can be repaired in a similar fashion, or through the Craft skill used
>     to create it. Generally speaking, this requires a DC 20 Craft check
>     and 1 hour of work per point of damage to be repaired. Most craftsmen
>     charge one-tenth the item’s total cost to repair such damage (more if
>     the item is badly damaged or ruined).

It doesn't seem to say that the weapon in question loses the masterwork quality, so if you repair it with a *mending* spell, it would still be a masterwork longsword.

Comment: Actually, even prior to a mending spell being cast, the item would STILL be a masterwork item, just broken. So, your attacks with it would be modified by -1 (-2 for broken, +1 for masterwork).